# SKAction.rotate not working?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I'm trying to create a node and animate it's zRotation property with an action, however, when attempting to run the action, the zRotation property of my node is not changed. I'm unsure why this isn't working.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

let aim = SKSpriteNode()

print(aim.zRotation)
aim.zRotation = CGFloat(Double.pi/2)
print(aim.zRotation)

let myAction = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: CGFloat(3.14), duration: 0)
aim.run(myAction)
print(aim.zRotation)
```

image of code with output

[image: image of code with output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SKAction will only be evaluated when your node is in a scene that is in turn being displayed in a view:

> An SKAction object is an action that is executed by a node in the
>   scene (SKScene). ... When the scene processes its nodes, actions
>   associated with those nodes are evaluated.

(From [Apple's SKAction documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction))

At the moment you have neither of those things so the action remains dormant. For an example of adding nodes to a scene and displaying that scene in a playground see [this from Swift Studies](http://www.swift-studies.com/blog/2014/6/4/playing-with-spritekit-in-a-swift-playground).

Comment: Thank you, once I added this node as a child to my scene object (myScene.addChild(aim)) the action was able to run!

Answer (score 1):

### I guess you want to achieve something like this

[image]

### Issues

There a a few errors in your code:

1. An action with duration 0 will instantly apply the change, better setting a greater value.
2. You are not presenting the SKView in Playground
3. Your SKSpriteNode has not image

### Solution

In Playground select View > Assistant > Show Assistant Editor in order to open a panel on the right where we'll add the SKView.

Now add this code an wait for the red square to appear in the Assistant Editor.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit

let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x:0 , y:0, width: 500, height: 500))

let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500))
scene.anchorPoint.x = 0.5
scene.anchorPoint.y = 0.5
sceneView.showsFPS = true
sceneView.presentScene(scene)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView

let square = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
square.fillColor = .red
scene.addChild(square)
square.run(.rotate(toAngle: 3.14, duration: 20))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I’m using the node rotation property to determine the angle a gun shoots, and thus don’t need to add an image to the node. When I added the node as a child of my scene object the action worked properly.